# Is it possible to change the CSS rules for Disqus comments?

Tags: disqus

I have tried everything I could come up with, including using the '!important' attribute, but have not been able to change the CSS for the Disqus comments on my site. Their CSS not only originates from a file on their website, but I think the comments are in an iframe or something, which would explain why the '!important' attribute isn't working. Is it possible to change the CSS for Disqus comments on a wordpress blog? All I want to add is the following code:

```
#disqus_thread {
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

That's it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Disqus comments are loaded in an iFrame, but you can do some modifications. Check out [Disqus Appearance Tweaks | DISQUS](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-appearance-tweaks)

You need to be able to use Dev Tools. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site and how to work with and change the CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading your themes style sheet after all plugins by giving it a high priority.

Here's an example of how its done for one specific theme.

```
add_action( 'genesis_setup', 'load_stylesheet' );

function load_stylesheet() {

remove_action( 'genesis_meta', 'load_stylesheet' );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheet', 999 );

}
```

I would check with your themes support and [Disqus support](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/545277-disqus-appearance-tweaks).